# extracting location_type from geocomplete (JQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, geolocation, geocomplete

I'm trying to use the jquery library [geocomplete](http://ubilabs.github.io/geocomplete/) to autocomplete a google address, and write to some hidden fields variables like the long, lat, location_type.  It works for lat,lng which get written out, but I'm pulling my hairs to get the location type.  Here's what I've tried:

```
#theJS

$(function(){
    $("#id_address").geocomplete()
      .bind("geocode:result", function(event, result){
        $.log(result.formatted_address);
          $("input#id_lat").val(result.geometry.location.lat());
          $("input#id_lng").val(result.geometry.location.lng());
          $("input#id_location_type").val(result.geometry.location_type());
      })
    });

#the HTML forms

<input id="id_lng" name="lng" type="hidden" />
<input id="id_lat" name="lat" type="hidden" />
<input id="id_location_type" name="location_type" type="text" />
<input type="text" name="address" id="id_address" />
```

To troubleshoot the results, I tried `$("input#id_location_type").val(result.geometry);` and it does write to the location_type input box `[object Object]`, but as soon as I extend it to `result.geometry.location_type` or `result.geometry.location_type()` I get nothing.

Any tips appreciated. (here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alphydan/5WeAC/) to clarify what I'm trying to to)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$("input#id_location_type").val(result.types);
```

instead of

```
$("input#id_location_type").val(result.geometry.location_type());
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically, You have to bind your geocode method with `geocode:result` and then you can extract `lat` and `lng`.

```
$("#location")
  .geocomplete()
  .bind("geocode:result", function (event, result) {
  $("#latitude").val(result.geometry.location.lat());
  $("#longitude").val(result.geometry.location.lng());
  //console.log(result);
});
```

You can read further  [here](https://www.w3schools.in/jquery/autocomplete-location-places-and-gather-all-location-related-data/)